# customize google map's InfoWindow

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I want to completely customize the infowindow in google maps v3? I just want to show a image there, No white rounded background with arrow.

Is it possible in v3? or any workaround?

Something like this

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

take a look at the sources of [this](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infowindow_custom/infowindow-custom.html) example - completely customized info window (Google Map API v3 is used).
I found that example on Google Map API v3 Group - "[Custom InfoWindow examples](http://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-js-api-v3/browse_thread/thread/4c99a6b558569a78?pli=1)" - just in case you will need more info

Comment: a more simpler approach http://blog.mridey.com/2009/09/label-overlay-example-for-google-maps.html

Answer (score -1):

If you just need a image as a marker, then you don't need an InfoWindow. You can set a custom image as a location marker.

```
pin=new google.maps.LatLng(50.00, 50.00);

if(marker) {
    marker.setMap(null);
}

var markerIcon = "car.png";

marker=new google.maps.Marker({
    position:pin,
    zIndexProcess: function( m )
    {
        return 9999999
    },
    icon:markerIcon
});

marker.setMap(map);

map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
```

Comment: This is only a marker, so if you have multiple markers in your map it will look like you have mutiple infoboxes opened. Also putting in HTML isn't quite easy... This is not a good solution for this problem.